# Make background image fill div no matter the image aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I can fill a `div`s background with an image. No matter what the aspect ratio of the image  (landscape or portrait). I tried to use several methods. Over `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: 100% 100%;` it doesn't always fill the div. The div has a landscape width/height ratio, the images do have a random ratio. If I try `background-size: cover;` the landscapes will fill the whole background, but the portrait ones will not (they have gaps on the left and right side).

Edit:

```
div { 
   background: url(img.png) no-repeat center center; 
   background-size: cover; 
   height: 100%; 
   width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: show us your codes. have u tried background-position: center; ?

Comment: `background-size:cover;` is the correct value. It will always fill the div, but the image will be cropped.

Comment: @APAD1 obviously the image will be cropped, but it doesn't work for me! See above.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qqxp2vnj/

Comment: @APAD1 interesting, it doesn't for me!

Comment: Hey is your div covering whole page?, i mean check giving border where your div starts and end. I think your div itself may not be filling the area you want.

Comment: pls see updated answer  with fiddle

Comment: Ya if the comment i gave is your issue go with @RachelGallen Answer, she is absolutely correct.

Comment: @APAD1 yours works fine. Sorry my mistake. Can either you or Rachel do an answer with `cover;`. I don't want to accept `vh/wh` units because of crossbrowser. Also `!important`, mehh

Comment: @APAD1 has the correct answer: a simple solution that has been around for ages.

Comment: @APAD1 correct answer, simply use `cover;` please make one.

Comment: this is what happens if you use cover and % http://jsfiddle.net/q9heqq24/2/

Comment: @RachelGallen I know what happens then, main reason why I gave yours not the accepted answer is use of `!important;`. I consider that bad practice.

Comment: @supersize upvotes cost nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size:cover;` should work for your needs. Basically, the `cover` value will cause the background image to completely fill the div, regardless of the orientation or size of the div, while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image. The one caveat to this solution is that the image will be cropped, since it has to stretch to fill the div.

[More info on the background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
div { 
   background: url(img.png) no-repeat center center; 
   background-size: contain; /*i think its better to use contain if you;re using a large png*/
   height: 100vh!important; 
   width: 100hw!important;
   overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to fill the whole page with an image. You are assuming that because of `100%` height and width values. But thats only because I have a parent div around it.

Comment: Hey @RachelGallen  I am with your answer, and ya i would like to know what 100hw means ?

Comment: @divy3993 100 horizontal width and vh is vertical height

Comment: @RachelGallen see my comment at OP.

Comment: Don't use `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100vw;`, but rather `min-height: 100%;` and `min-width: 100%;` because if you use vh (viewport-height) and vw (viewport width) the image will _always_ be stretched relative to the viewport, not to the parent element, which is unwanted behaviour.

Comment: use cover for smaller images and contain for v large images